# How to know a timezone of a timestamp in postgresql 8.3

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I'm using postgresql 8.3 and i would like to know the timezone of a particular timestamp (a column in a table).

In the documentation i've found the keyword ["timezone"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-datetime.html)

But i don't understand how to apply it in a column of table. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume you have a column named `ct` which has the type `TIMESTAMPTZ` in the table `t`. Then you can use:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM ct) FROM t;
```

to get the offset of the timezone in seconds. It that gives you `3600` from `UTC`/`GMT` that means either `GMT+1`, `CET` or whatever. The value returned depends on your `TIMEZONE` setting.

Sample (I live in Germany, actual timezone ist `GMT+1`/`CET`):

```
test=# select '2008-01-01 12:00:00 GMT+5'::timestamptz;
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2008-01-01 18:00:00+01

test=# set timezone to 'gmt';
SET
test=# select '2008-01-01 12:00:00 GMT+5'::timestamptz;
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2008-01-01 17:00:00+00
```

As you can see it always outputs anything in the configured timezone. So the offset you will get with `EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM ...)` depends on your `TIMEZONE` setting. The timezone which was given on `INSERT` is lost, because it is not worth to be saved. The thing that counts is that everything is correct and that should not depend on the `TIMEZONE` setting. PostgreSQL does that very well.

Answer (score 12):

"PostgreSQL does that very well."

I really like PostgreSQL, but in this particular feature it does not do it well. Timezone is not only offset to GMT. Timezone is tight to political rules that implies daylight saving. As there are plenty of timezones with the same offset and different daylight saving rules - when PG forgets about original timezone it looses the information in fact.

Personally I store original timezone separately for the dates it matters in the form 'America/New_York'. If anybody has better solution - it's welcome.

Comment: yep, and the pg type name 'timestamp with timezone' is misleading. The information really saved in the database is the same than 'timestamp without timezone'. The only thing that changes are on-the-fly conversion to/from UTC to whatever your global timezone were or is at input and output moment. So pg type 'timestamp with timezone' DO NOT SAVE timezone info.

Answer (score 4):

In Postgres the original input timezone is lost even if you store the datetime value in *timestamp with time zone* data type.

**Disadvantage:**
Say if I have datetime data(along with timezone info) of when people use their facebook app all over the world. Now I store those values in *timestamp with time zone* data type. One random day I want to see how heavily people use their FB app in the morning compared to at night and if the same trend is seen across countries.
But wait, I no longer have the timezone information. 
Sitting in D.C., what I can see is how the activity panned out all over the world when it was 10am EST.

**Advantage:**
If you are comparing two datasources with timestamp of same timezone but one was stored as what the local watch was showing while other stored by converting it to UTC. Here what you can do is just store the timestamp in the timestamptz datatype and tell which timezone it belongs to and then you can compare them easily.
For example,
An activity in PST timezone was recorded at `2014-10-19 10:23:54`. Now two separate data sources stored it separately. Datasource1 stored it as `2004-10-19 10:23:54 PST`, Datasource2 stored it as `2014-10-19 18:23:54 UTC`. If they are stored in the *timestamptz* datatype, it will show you the same time when you do

```
SELECT datasource1.time, datasource2.time
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the timestampz is recoreded for an instant in time in ZULU/GMT time, which never changes it's offset (since it's the reference), it is not necessary to record the timezone. You need only add/subtract the offset to the GEOPOLITICAL time zone offset in the PAST, PRESENT, or FUTURE.

You *DO* need to know the exact GEOPOLITICAL TIMEZONE in effect at the location the time applies to at the moment applies to for PAST and PRESENT purposes.

For future instances in time purposes, this gets more problematic, maybe. It should still work though. Think of sunset. If some location earth has a sunset @ midnight ZULU time (somewhere over the Atlantic Ocean or Northern Canada to Alaska in winter in the Northern Hemisphere), and that time is assumed to be 8 PM ( -4:00 offset) in that location at the moment you record it in the system  and you record it as 'winter-date-in-future 8:00 PM' it will be recorded as 24:00 GMT in the database.

Now, that location on earth gets a hair up its *ss and thumbs its nose at geographical related time reckoning, and calls their time zone - '+11:55'. So for them when it's midnight in England (GMT midnight) they WANT to call it 11:55 AM, totally their choice. When any computer wants to display that date in the future for that location (i.e. that geopolitical timezone), they will call it 11:55 AM, even if the sun is setting. And of course, it WILL be the day AHEAD of the day you planned it :-) Their problem.