# SQL Server variant from Oracle TZ_OFFSET

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, timezone, offset

The execution of following SQL in Oracle:

```
SELECT TZ_OFFSET('Europe/Brussels') from dual;
```

returns the value +02:00

Note that this function can be used for any timezone in Olsson notation. It's not about the database server.

I was wondering if there exists a similar function in MS Sql Server where you can ask the offset of a given timezone (in the microsoft timezone notation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server timezone offset value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335438/server-timezone-offset-value)

Comment: That goes only about the database server timezone, my question goes about any timezone

Comment: what you actually want? Query for  SQL server? or oracle ?

Comment: I'm looking for Sql Server, I gave the Oracle example of what I want in Sql Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SQL 2016 onward, and in Azure SQL Database, you can achieve this with:

```
SELECT DATENAME(tz, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time')

-- Output: '+02:00'
```

Notice the time zone names are *Windows* time zone identifiers, not the IANA TZ (aka Olson) identifiers.  For more on the differences, see [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

If you want to use IANA TZ identifiers, or if you are using an older version of SQL Server that doesn't have the `AT TIME ZONE` function, then you can use my [SQL Server Time Zone Support project](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport), with the following:

```
SELECT DATENAME(tz, Tzdb.SwitchZone(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), 'Europe/Brussels'))

-- Output: '+02:00'
```

Also, note that an offset can only be computed for a time zone at a particular reference point.  In my examples, you can see I have chosen the current system time with `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`.  (The current time is *implicit* with Oracle's `TZ_OFFSET` function.)